# Can I pass a URL to AWS SDK to upload that file?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I was wondering if it is possible to import images through an URL on AWS (Amazon S3).

Suppose I have this image url:

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13259089_1690703004512017_446506721_n.jpg`
```

Can I pass it to AWS so that it gets imported directly? If not, do I have to download the image onto my server so that I can upload it to AWS?

Comment: You're question is confusing. You ask about uploading twice but then ask if you can download by URL? What are you really asking? Do you already know the URL and want to download it? Or do you want to set the filename when you upload it? Are you doing this thru a form or by standalone function?

Comment: i have only url file not it`s content  so my question is can i pass this url to aws sdk for uploading it instead of file content ?

Comment: @dbmitch i think he wants to know, whether aws has a way to import from a given URL or if he first hast to download the image himself, so that afterwards it can be uploaded to aws

Comment: @FlorianKoch Exactly ! thank you.

Comment: Someone's done it with jquery. You must own the s3 bucket. Not sure if it works with HTTPS though. Check out links beside your question.https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/

Comment: @dbmitch thank you , but that post doesn`t answer my question , can you please read the question again !